# Sample Ajax program for JSP+Servlets+Hibernate

Tags: java, ajax, hibernate, model-view-controller, jsp

In my app im using JSP as view,servlet as controller,hibernate as model..

in that app jsp pages im have to fill form while creating new user with fields like username and all.

now i want to use AJAX code to check if username name with entered name in form is already there in the database or not...

can any1 guide me how to write coding for this as well as the control flow..

i have googled but didnt got any idea how to do this requirement..

thanks in advance

Comment: There are a plenty of resources on the web which could get you started. THis could be one of them : http://javapapers.com/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function VerifyUsername()
    {
        //alert("In Verify Method");
        var name=document.getElementById("username").value;
        //alert(name);
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            //alert("http");
         }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            alert("http active");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            //alert("in Function()");
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                try
                {
                    //alert("In Try");
                    document.getElementById("errorpass").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    /*var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    alert(response);
                    if(response.toString()=='notmatch')
                    {
                        alert("Ok");
                        document.getElementById("errorpass").innerHTML ="OK";
                    }
                    if(response =='match')
                    {
                        alert("Not Ok");
                        document.getElementById("errorpass").innerHTML ="Take Other Name.";
                    }*/
                }
                catch(ex)
                {
                    alert("Exception in function "+ex);
                }
            }
        }
        //xmlhttp.open("POST","servlet/UsernamePresence_Serv?UserId"+name,true);
        xmlhttp.open("POST","servlet/UsernamePresence_Serv?"+name,true);
        var params = "UserId="+name;
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); 
        xmlhttp.send(params);
    }
</script>
```

in Servlet

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try
    {
        Session session=Hibernate_Class.sessionObject();
        String userID=null;
        userID = request.getParameter("UserId");

        login_model loginModel_Obj=new login_model();
        loginModel_Obj._Name=userID;
        System.out.print("at "+userID);
        boolean username_bool=Hibernate_Class.usernamePresence(loginModel_Obj, session);

        if (username_bool)
        {
            out.println("Username Present In Database");
        }
        else
        {
            out.println("Username Not Present In Database");
        }

    }
    finally{}
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are having two option for user name validation.

1>  Client(User Interface) Side validation
  2>  Server side validation

For option 1>, you need to write ajax call which will make a request to server and respond a result which will inform if a use is valid or not.

For client side, I will suggest you to use java script OR jQuery.
  Here is the sample jQuery ajax code.

```
  $.ajax({
   url: "validateUser.html?username=username",
   success:function(data){
      //YOUR CODE FOR FUTHRE ACTION FOR VALID/INVALID ACTION
   }
  });
```

You can refer jQuery ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
  For option 2>, validation on server side...

You can validate the user name on submit of the form.

you can retrieve the value by request.getParamter("userName"); and check into the DB if it already there OR not.

Regards,
Gunjan.

Answer (score -1):

In Below code just replace JDBC code with your Hibernate Code .

**JSP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://
www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title> - User Login</title>

<style type="text/css">

#marqueecontainer{
position: relative;
width: 150px; /*marquee width */
height: 163px; /*marquee height */
/*background-color: white;*/
overflow: hidden;
/*border: 3px solid orange;
padding: 2px;
padding-left: 4px;*/

}

</style>
</head>
<script language="javascript">

var mWindow="windows";
var objLogRequest;



function chekUserId()
{
try
{
if(document.getElementById("userID").value=="")
{
alert(" You have not entered Username. ");
return 0;
}
if(document.getElementById("userPass").value=="")
{
alert("You have not entered Password.");
return 0;
}

var userId = document.getElementById("userID").value;
var userPass = document.getElementById("userPass").value;

//alert("userId:->"+userId);
//alert("userPass:->"+userPass);
serUrl ='/servlet/UserLogin?userID='+userId
+'&userPass='+userPass+'&randomNum='+Math.random()*Math.random();
//alert("serUrl:->"+serUrl);
if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
objLogRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
//alert("Windos Browser");
}
else
{
objLogRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
mWindow = "nonWindows";
}
if(objLogRequest)
{
//alert("objAddRequest 1");
objLogRequest.onreadystatechange = sendLogInfo;
//alert("objAddRequest 2");
objLogRequest.open('Get',serUrl);
//alert("objAddRequest 3");
if(mWindow=='nonWindows')
{
objLogRequest.send('');
}
else
{
//alert("before send ");
objLogRequest.send();
//alert("after send ");
}
}

}// end try
catch(e)
{
alert("Exception in chekUserId function "+e);
}

}
function sendLogInfo()
{
try
{
//alert('object state :-> '+objLogRequest.readyState)
if(objLogRequest.readyState==4)
{
if(objLogRequest.status==200)
{
var response = objLogRequest.responseText;
//alert('response :-> '+response)

if(response =='notmatch')
{

document.getElementById("errorpass").innerHTML ="Username and
password do not match.(You provided
"+document.getElementById("userID").value+" )";
document.getElementById("userPass").value="";

}
if(response =='match')
{
alert('user valid');
}
}
}
}
catch(ex)
{
alert("Exception in sendInfo function "+ex);
}
}

</script>
<body marginheight="0" marginwidth='0' topmargin='0'
bottommargin='0'leftmargin='0' class="body">
<table width="751" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0"
cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#000099"><table width="751" border="0"
cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table width="751" border="0"
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="25" align="left" valign="middle"
bgcolor="#C7C7C7" class="plan-a-trip"><span class="welcometext"></
span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="10" align="left" valign="top"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><table width="751" border="0" cellspacing="0"
cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="10" align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</
td>
<td width="150" align="left" valign="top">
</td>
<td width="10" align="left" valign="top"></td>
<td width="571" height="270" align="left"
valign="top" bgcolor="#999999"><table width="571" border="0"
cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="579" height="476" align="left"
valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<table width="571" height="391" border="0" cellpadding="0"
cellspacing="0">
<form name='loginform' method='get' action='/servlet/UserLogin'
onSubmit="return submit(document.loginform);" >
<tr>
<td width="25" rowspan="11" align="left"
valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="459" height="20" align="left"
valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="20" rowspan="11" align="left"
valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="16" align="left"
valign="middle"><img src="/image/PlanATrip/UserLogin/member_login.jpg"
width="120" height="13" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="10" align="left"
valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="5" align="left" valign="top"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="100" align="left"
valign="top"><table width="479" height="115" border="0"
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="85" align="left"
valign="middle" class="text">Username</td>
<td width="10" rowspan="6" align="left"
valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="376">
<input id="userID" name="userID"
type="text" class="inputtext" maxLength="25"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="5" align="left"
valign="middle"></td>
<td height="5" align="left" valign="top"></
td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle"
class="text">Passward</td>
<td><input id="userPass" name="userPass"
type="password" maxlength="15" class="inputtext" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="5" align="left"
valign="middle"></td>
<td height="5" align="left" valign="top"
class="wrongpass" id="errorpass">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</
td>
<td><input name="loginBut" type="button"
id="loginBut" class="searchButton" value="Login"
onclick="chekUserId()"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</
td>
<td ><a href="/servlets/Registration.html"
class="fyp">New User Sign Up</a></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td height="10" align="left"
valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>

</tr>
</form>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
<td width="10" align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</
td>
</tr>

</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Servlet Code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class UserLogin extends HttpServlet
{

public String DBUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/
databasename";

public void init ()
{
//getCon();
System.out.println("UserLogin called");
}



public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException
{


res.setContentType("text/html");

PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

ResultSet rs=null;

Connection con = null;
Statement stm=null;



//Vector userId;

String userID=null,userPass=null,currentDate=null;
userID = req.getParameter("userID");
userPass = req.getParameter("userPass");
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);


try
{

con = pool.getCon();
stm = con.createStatement();
//System.out.println("connect");

////chek user ID Start ***//////
String querySelctId = "select count(*)user from userinfo where
UserId='"+userID+"'AND UserPassword='"+userPass+"';";

rs = stm.executeQuery(querySelctId);

//System.out.println("4");
int count = 0
try{
count = rs.getString(1);
}catch(SQLException sqlEx){
System.out.println("sqlEx");
}catch(Exception ex){
System.out.println("Ex");
}

if(count==1)
{
System.out.println(userID+":-> Login");

out.print("match");
}
else
{
out.print("notmatch");

}


}

catch (SQLException sqle)
{
System.out.println("SQLException");
System.out.println(sqle);
//res.sendRedirect("/servlets/RegistrationFail.html");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
System.out.println("Exception");
System.out.println(ex);
res.sendRedirect("/servlets/ErrorPage.htm");

}
finally
{
try
{
if(con != null)
{
System.out.print("UserLogin Servlet release:-> ");
pool.releaseConnection(con);
rs.close();
stm.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
}
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
System.out.println(" Exception in release the connection ");
System.out.println(Ex);
}

}
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
doPost(req,res);
}





public Connection getCon()
{
Connection con = null;

try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(DBUrl,"root","");
databaseMetaData = con.getMetaData();
stm = con.createStatement();
}catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e)
{
System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");

System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}catch (SQLException sqle)
{
System.out.println("SQLException");
System.out.println(sqle);
}catch (Exception ex)
{
System.out.println("Exception");
System.out.println(ex);
}
return con;
}
}
```

Comment: getng null value in servlet instead of userId and userPass,,,